# how to get unique value from column 2 and and corresponding maximum value from column 1 in tcl

Tags: tcl

My test file contains :

```
2  server[0]/asm
3  server[1]/asm
5  server[1]/pst
6  server[0]/pst
3  server[2]/qrf
5  server[1]/qrf
.
.
and so on
```

I need results something as :

```
3  asm
6  pst
5  qrf
```

I have tried something like this till now:

```
set fp [open ./txt r]
set fw [open ./txt w]
while {[gets $fp line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp {\[0\]} $line]} {
        puts $fw [string map {server\[0\]/ ""} $line]
    } eslsif {[regexp {\[1\]} $line]} {
        puts $fw [string map {server\[1\]/ ""} $line]
    } elseif {[regexp {\[2\]} $line]} {
        puts $fw [string map {server\[2\]/ ""} $line]
    }
}
close $fp
close $fw
```

The output till now is:

```
2 asm
3 asm
5 pst
6 pst
3 qrf
5 qrf
```

There are only 3 servers. server[0], server [1] and server[2].
So i want maximum value from column 1 for the same last name in column 2 in tcl.

Please guide me through it.

Comment: What have you done so far to solve it?

Comment: I have set variables as server[0] and server[1] etc . I am parsing through each line and then i am using string map for these variable to replace with " ".

Comment: Now how to map with the maximum value. Right now i am working on it.

Comment: You're getting downvotes because you're not showing any of your code, btw.

Comment: I have put my code now.. help me understand the next step to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regular expression to pick out the parts of each line

```
set names [dict create]
while {[gets $f line] != -1} {
    if {[regexp {^(\d+).*/(.*)$} $line -> num name]} {
        dict lappend names $name $num
    }
}

dict for {name nums} $names {
    puts [list [tcl::mathfunc::max {*}$nums] $name]
}
```